# What determines the speed in which a dropshot explodes?

Tags: gears-of-war-4

I have had several matches where I am battling  using the dropshot and my rounds take 1-2 seconds longer to explode/drop from the sky when I release them.  What causes this?  Is it the radius of the enemy in relation to the shot dropshot?

*It does not appear to be latency as my connection and other gnasher battles appear fine.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this delay is caused by the kind of surface that the dropshot drops onto.  Here is what I have been able to determine:

**If the dropshot falls onto a surface that it can dig into, there is a small delay before the explosion occurs.**

On the map Fallout, I shot a dropshot and released the trigger for the dropshot to drop to the ground.  If the surface was dirt, the dropshot would stick in the ground for a short time (~1 second) and then detonate.  You can actually see the dropshot round sticking out of the dirt if you are close enough.

**If the dropshot falls onto a surface that it cannot dig into, it detonates immediately.**

Again, on the map Fallout, when I shot the dropshot and then released the trigger for it to fall, if it hit a surface that it could not dig into, it would detonate immediately.  The surface in this case was metal flooring.

In addition, if you shoot a Dropshot and release the trigger immediately or within a fraction of a second of firing, it has a delay before it detonates, and bounces around some.  This is likely to discourage close-quarter use of the Dropshot.